# Control rails application from Iphone's cucumber

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm using Frank to test my iPhone app's features.
The iPhone app is synchronizing data from a rails application and I would like to cover the synchronization process with acceptance tests.
I would like to be able to use the standard ruby commands to manage my rails application's data for example creating a table of products in rails app and then i can check that it  gets synchronized on the iPhone.
How can i configure cucumber (or Frank) so i can use Product.find_by_name("productname") from my iphone's tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hacking this together:

https://gist.github.com/2033123

Stick it in Frank/features/support

I'm not a great Rails dev so someone could probably clean it up but it works for our purposes.